# jQueryUI transfer effect: several simultaneous transfers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation, transfer

Consider this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NbWJn/).

```
function transfer() {
    source.effect('transfer', { to: target }, 2000);
}
setInterval(transfer, 500);
```

As you can see the transfers run in series.
How do you make them run simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery animations queue by default. If you look at the [documentation for `.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options), you'll see that there's a `queue` option to disable this behavior. You can use this with jQuery UI's `.effect()` method as well. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NbWJn/2/) for an example.

I've [filed an issue](https://github.com/jquery/api.jqueryui.com/issues/118) to document this in the [`.effect()` documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/effect/).